# Subscribe/Consume headline XMPP messages

Tags: java, xmpp, publish-subscribe, openfire, smack

How to subscribe or consume XMPP messages sent from a user.  These messages are of type "line"?  Kindly give me a solution.  I am using OpenFire server and Smack library.

Answer (score 0):

Register a StanzaListener with a Filter for Messages of type Headline.

Comment: Thank you Flow.  Is there any other solution other than StanzaListener?

Comment: No, it's the most low-level API Smack provides to listen for incoming stanza (and optionally filter them by certain predicates, like the message type).

Comment: My usecase is like this : user1 publishes messages to user2 for every one second.  user3 consumes the same message that is published in user2 at the same time.  Kindly give suggest me a solution.  Thanks in advance.